# MPI Recv data getting corrupted

Tags: java, mpi, openmpi

I'm trying to send a number across using MPI, but the data is getting corrupted. I can't figure out why. My code is:

```
import mpi.*;

public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws MPIException{
        MPI.Init(args);
        int rank = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Rank();
        int clusterSize = MPI.COMM_WORLD.Size();
        int[] send = new int[1];
        int[] recv = new int[1];
        send[0] = 12387394;
        if(rank == 0) {
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(send[0], 0, 1, MPI.INT, 1, 17);
        } else {
            MPI.COMM_WORLD.Recv(recv, 0, 1, MPI.INT, 0, 17);
            System.out.println(recv[0]);
        }
        MPI.Finalize();

    }
}
```

The output I get is `1`. Why is that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shouldn't you pass the whole array as a buffer instead of the first value? I mean:

```
MPI.COMM_WORLD.Send(send, 0, 1, MPI.INT, 1, 17);
```